# Configure elasticsearch to not index a field and consider just as a object

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, gsub

I have a situation where I need to put some dynamic data(of which shape cannot be determine and its very random) into an elastic search instance

Eg:

```
       LOG_DATA": {
        "\u0000*\u0000message": "=",
        "\u0000*\u0000code": 0,
        "\u0000*\u0000file": "/JEntity/Logger/RedwineLogger.php",
        "\u0000*\u0000line": 205,
        "\u0000Exception\u0000trace": [
          {
            "function": "aliceShutdownHandler",
            "args": []
          }
        ],
        "\u0000Exception\u0000previous": null,
        "\u0000*\u0000severity": 1
      },
      "Message": "Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' ",
      "File": "/shop/www/htdocs/shop.live",
      "Line": 205,
      "STACK_TRACE": "#0 [internal function]: aliceShutdownHandler()\n#1 {main}",
      "customer_session_id": "tcph057qgkme8u0vv3tc5c1bf63ebvk7",
      "DeviceOS": "Unknown OS Platform",
      "NAMESPACE": "default",
      "index_date": "2015.04.16"
```

This is a log what I get from one of my service and which is pushed by the service to a rabbitmq.

A logstash instance is listening to this queue and pushing the data to a elastic search after modifying it slightly.

- I found that the LOG_DATA have lots of "\u0000" in field name and value. How can I remove those "\u0000";
- The LOG_DATA can contain any data and its keep on varying and unpredictable. I dont want the elasticsearch to index this data, just need to store this as is. And the type of fields are not predictable. But elastic search created a index with the first documents field mapping, and after that I am always getting field mapping exception. How Can I make the ES to not check type and not do index for this field.

  - How can I delete LOG_DATA.\u0000Exception\u0000trace.args field

It will be really helpful if I can have insight to these problems

Comment: Have you tried changing the charset of the input stream in the logstash configuration? http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/codecs/plain#charset If you know the input log stream is always going to be a single charset, then you should be able to make that change and have the \u0000 characters not appear in the stored document

Comment: Yes, default it uses UTF-8, which one I can use instead

Comment: And I am reciving input from RabbitMq, not from a file, RabbitMq input now does not support charset
http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/inputs/rabbitmq#auto_delete

Comment: Charsets are part of the codec setting http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/rabbitmq#codec and http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/codecs/plain#charset

Comment: Can somebody help  me on the second problem